# how to get the value from redux store and display it using typescirpt and redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I am working on react typescript and redux toolkit project
I have feteched api response using axios and assign  the response  to redux store ,but when tried to get the value the from the store it information is not display

**User.tsx**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { UserService } from "../service/UserService";
import {useAppDispatch,useAppSelector} from '../redux/hooks'
import {DeleteCard, Getall} from '../redux/ActionSlice'
import {AiOutlineStar} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {IUser} from "../model/User";
import { AddFavourite } from "../redux/FavouriteSlice";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
interface ISTATE{
    loading:boolean,
    users:IUser[],
    errorMsg:string,
}

const User:React.FC=()=>{
  const product=useAppSelector(state=>state.app.action)
  const navigate=useNavigate()
  const dispatch=useAppDispatch()
  const[state,setState]=useState<ISTATE>({
    loading:false,
    users:[] as IUser[],
    errorMsg:''
  })

  useEffect(()=>{
    UserService.getAllUsers().then(res=>dispatch(Getall(res.data.products))).catch(err=>setState({...state,loading:false,errorMsg:err}))
    setState({...state,loading:false,users:product}) 
    console.log(state.users)
  },[])
 
  const AddFav=(product:IUser)=>{
    dispatch(AddFavourite(product))
  }
    return(
        <div className="flex flex-wrap space-x-4  space-y-4 justify-center items-center">
         {state.users.length >0 && state.users.map((product,i)=>(
            <div key={i} className="flex flex-col items-center relative bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg shadow-zinc-400">
                <img src={product.avatar} alt="image" className="h-[300px] w-[300px] p-2 mt-6 object-contain "/>
                <h1 className="text-md m-2 w-full text-center font-medium">{product.name}</h1> 
                <h1>{product.developerEmail}</h1>
                <button onClick={()=>AddFav(product)} className="absolute top-0 right-0 p-2"><AiOutlineStar className="text-xl"/></button>
                <button onClick={()=>{dispatch(DeleteCard(product._id))}} className="bg-red-500 px-4 py-2 mt-2 rounded-md mb-2 text-white shadow-lg">Delete</button>
                <button onClick={()=>navigate(`/details/${product._id}`)}>More details</button>
            </div>
         ))}
        </div>
    ) 

}
export default User
```

**Action Slice**

```
import{createSlice,PayloadAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { IUser } from '../model/User'
import { RootState } from './store'

const initialState:IUser[]=[]

const ActionSlice=createSlice({
    name:'action',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        Getall:(state,action:PayloadAction<IUser>)=>{
            state.push(action.payload)
        },
        DeleteCard:(state,action:PayloadAction<string>)=>{
           const index = state.findIndex((todo) => todo._id === action.payload);
            state.splice(index, 1);
         },


         
    }

})
export const {DeleteCard,Getall}=ActionSlice.actions;
export const getProductList=(state:RootState)=>state.app.action
export default ActionSlice.reducer
```

**IUser interface**

```
export interface IUser{
    _id:string;
    avatar:string;
    name:string;
    category:string;
    description:string;
    developerEmail:string;
    price:number,
    
}
```

I have tried googling staff but would able to get solution to display the thing,it would be great if you guys help me out to figure out the solution

**thank you in advance**

Comment: can you show your `store` code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fast-3x0klj you can find it here

Comment: sorry sir, you give me an empty app?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fast-3x0klj?file=/src/store.tsx

Comment: I see you are missing defining hooks. follow [this guide](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript) to set up redux for react/typescript

Comment: i have already defining those in hooks.tsx file